# Apply CSS template to ASP page containing content/controls

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm after some help applying for the correct syntax applying CSS layout to Asp controls/content.

For a normal `.aspx` page I usually link to the CSS templates in the header similar to the following.....

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Project.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/newtheme/css/reset.css" 
    type="text/css" media="screen">
       <%--....etc--%>
  <script>
       <%--....etc--%>
  </script>
</head>
       <%--....etc--%>
<body id="page1">
       <%--....etc--%>     
</body>

</html>
```

How do I apply a similar CSS template to controls where the basic page structure is in the following format?

```
<%@ Page Title="Login" Language="C#" 
      MasterPageFile="~/themes/default/default.master" 
      AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="login" 
      EnableViewState="false" Codebehind="login.aspx.cs" %>
<%@ Register Src="controls/login-with-captcha.ascx" 
      TagName="LoginWithCaptcha" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
       <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
       runat="Server">
  <uc1:LoginWithCaptcha ID="LoginWithCaptcha1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it in `Content1` OR `Content2`, but i sugest in `Content1` actualy its the master head!

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">

       <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"/>

       <link type...................YOUR CLASS............>

</asp:Content>
```